# Paypal express checkout works locally but not in production in rails. Returns an error called No Token Passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

Using express checkout and activemerchant gem in rails I created a wallet feature where in you can add funds into the wallet through paypal(express checkout). This works locally but not in production.

In production as soon as I click the paypal checkout button I am redirected to the following url with no token(as you can see)

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=

The only thing on the blank page here is "No token passed"

Here is a log from the production in heroku
[image]

In local development set up for the same action I get:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=-ubDPzpaPpBkgHFsZshLh8PR4jHMxWQYbCjt5Wlq2Tcj8SAtu0iW3Vysmhq&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0fb0124e9b61f737ba21b0819848475f0da5465a2ea26eae033cbe3bda

(I removed a few characters from the session so the above url wont work)
with an option to make payments.

Here is a screenshot of the dev log
[image]

The following is the relevant code:

```
def express_checkout
    response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(BigDecimal.new(params[:amount])*100,
        ip: request.remote_ip,
        return_url: new_payment_url,
        cancel_return_url: wallet_url,
        currency: "USD",
        allow_guest_checkout: true,
        items: [{name: "Add Money", description: "Adds money to wallet ", amount: BigDecimal.new(params[:amount])*100}]
    )
    redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
end
```

The following is all the code related to it. The code is split into the following filenames as titles - activemerchant.rb, payments_controller.rb, payment.rb and wallet.html.erb

http://pastebin.com/caAGd2ST

Can you tell me why this works in dev and not in production and what I should do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the yml configuration for production environment. Usually, these 3rd party integrations require a yml file with the config / settings per environment. Specially PayPal, when they have different IDs, Secrets, etc.

Based on your comment, it seems your environment variables are not being loaded for production environment.

Comment: I am using environment variables for the same. This is how I set them up.


  ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = `ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(
    login: ENV['PAYPAL_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['PAYPAL_PASSWORD'],
    signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SIGNATURE']
  )`

Answer (score 1):

When I faced this issue what worked for me is, ENV variables we not set properly in prod (or) I messed up setting the ENV variables. I tried hard coding the values just to check if thats the issue and for me that was the issue. Later removed the hardcoded values and I have set ENV variables properly.

However having such details hardcoded is a very bad practice, just for testing you can try that approach.